# J2ME - Soft keyboard / Virtual keyboard library?

Tags: java-me, touch, libraries, virtual-keyboard

I have created a J2ME app (all custom coded using Canvas for each screen) that works great on devices with keypads, but when the device has no keypad and no virtual keypad/keyboard (eg, some Nokia Asha devices) then the app cannot be used.

Is there a keyboard/keypad library I can plug into my app?

The main reason I need the keyboard/keypad is because the app has a search screen (Canvas) where the user can type in their query.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any library, but thought I'd just share how I usually do it myself.

I usually implement my own touch input, by dividing the screen into 9 or 12 invisible fields. The upper left field is then equal to pressing 1. The upper center field is equal to pressing 2 and so forth.
You receive these inputs by `pointerPressed()` and then simple check where on the screen the user has pressed, and the call `keyPressed()` accordingly.

E.g.

```
public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
  if (x < width/3 && y < height/4) keyPressed(KEY_NUM1);
  else if (x >= width/3 && x < width*2/3 && y < height/4) keyPressed(KEY_NUM2);
  else if (x >= width*2/3 && y < height/4) keyPressed(KEY_NUM3);
  ...and so forth
}
```

If you wish, you can then add a semi-transparent keypad graphics layer on top of the GUI, e.g. after checking `hasPointerEvents()`.

I have used this approach for many of my apps, and find that it works a lot better than other have-to-hit-a-very-small-button-on-the-screen solutions.

Comment: Thanks for this. Presumably, all touchscreen devices must show a virtual keypad/keyboard when a TextBox screen is being displayed? (If so, I could just use a touch event to show the TextBox screen.)

Comment: Yes, using a `TextBox` is another option. (But I thought you were using strictly `Canvas`).

Comment: Yes, that was the initial requirement, but TextBox could be a good compromise.

Comment: That should do fine. I used that approach myself in lublu.dk/SimpleList.jar (lets you add/remove lines in text-files via FTP connection. Using it as a shopping list myself).